# MSSQL Groupby Order by

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a query that return the monthname and count the for that month.

```
    SELECT   DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(AE.BookingTimeStamp ) , -1 ))   monthnames, count (BookingTimeStamp)  totCount
FROM BookingsAEItems AE  WHERE BookingTimeStamp BETWEEN '1/12/2015' AND '1/12/2016' group by monthnames   order by totCount
```

I am getting

> Invalid column name 'monthnames'.

This is an MSSQL Query. 
What am i Missing !!!

Comment: You cannot group by monthnames because your table does not have a column named monthnames. You have to group by `DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(AE.BookingTimeStamp ) , -1 ))`

Comment: Thanks @zespri for the info, Then how can i return count vs month name for the above query

Comment: You can simplify and make the query more readable, if you passed `BookingTimeStamp` to the `DateName` function without also calling the  `DateAdd` function. i.e.   `DateName( month , AE.BookingTimeStamp ) as monthnames`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback...  I got it working by having inner query as given in the comments

```
 SELECT Months.monthnames, count(BookingTimeStamp)
    FROM BookingsAEItems AE, (SELECT distinct DateName(month, DateAdd(month, MONTH(AE.BookingTimeStamp ), -1 )) 'monthnames'
    FROM BookingsAEItems AE  WHERE BookingTimeStamp BETWEEN '1/10/2015' AND '12/12/2016') Months
    WHERE AE.BookingTimeStamp BETWEEN '1/10/2015' AND '12/12/2016' 
    And DateName(month, DateAdd(month, MONTH(AE.BookingTimeStamp ), -1 )) = Months.monthnames
    group by Months.monthnames
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias in the `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause. You would have to repeat the entire expression:

```
SELECT   DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(AE.BookingTimeStamp ) , -1 ))   monthnames,
         count (BookingTimeStamp)  totCount
FROM     BookingsAEItems AE
WHERE    BookingTimeStamp BETWEEN '1/12/2015' AND '1/12/2016'
group by DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(AE.BookingTimeStamp ) , -1 ))
order by totCount
```